# Running a WinCE 2013 app on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-ce

Is there any way to run an app built for Windows Compact Embedded 2013 on regular Windows (i.e., Windows 7)? I know that you could do it for WinCE 5, but it looks like for CE 2013, I may have to compile it differently.

Comment: Have you tried emulators? But you would have to compile under x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It's not possible to run an app built for Windows Embedded Compact 2013 (WEC2013) on regular Windows (Windows desktop).

You may need to compile it or sometimes modify the source code also.